# PHP with xml file

Tags: php, html, xml, xml-parsing

I am new to PHP and I have a problem.

I wanna load all XML files, which I upload before that in a server, of  application directory in combobox. When I click on combobox it shows me `xmlfile1` `xmlfile2` etc.....

How can i do this on PHP?

Thanks!!

At the moment i just have the next code:

Practise.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Práctica PHP</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>File Upload:</h3>
    Selecciona un fichero a subir: <br />
    <form action="cargaFichero.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="uploadedfile" size="50" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Subir Fichero" />   

    <select name="seleccionArchivo">
            <option selected="selected" value=''>--Selecciona archivo--</option>
    </select>
</body>
```

cargaFichero.php:

```
<?php
$target_path = "Repositorio/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "El archivo ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
    " ha sido subido correctamente";
} else{
    echo "Hubo un error al subir el archivo, intentalo de nuevo!";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use scan_dir: http://ch2.php.net/manual/de/function.scandir.php

```
$files = scandir($target_path);
print_r($files);
```

**UPDATE:**

You can add them to the select box using a foreach loop:

```
$options = '';
foreach($files as $file){
  if(preg_match('/\.xml$/',$file))
    $options .= '<option value="'.$file.'">'.$file.'</option>';
}

echo $options;
```

Comment: Once i load the files of the directory in this path, how can i share this files in the list of selects of the combobox???

Comment: I keep wihtout understand one thing. When in upload que file, the app shares another screen with que correct message of uploading file. But i dont want to do that. I need when i upload the file, this load into the combobox list to select.